# Integral of the square of the absolute value of a function

Tags: integration, normed-spaces, absolute-value

I have been trying to solve this question and have looked to see if this has  been asked but it has not.  I am given this assumption:

\begin{equation}
\|f(x)\|^2 = 1
\end{equation}

From there I know to rewrite this given expression as an integral using the definition of a norm of a function.

\begin{equation}
\|f(x)\|^2 = 1 = \sqrt{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|^2 \,dx  }^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|^2 \,dx 
\end{equation}

After simplifying, the part that I do not know how to do is how to solve:

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|^2 \,dx 
\end{equation}

I do not have an expression to replace f(x) with.  I do know that I am supposed to solve using integration by parts but I do not know how.  Any help is appreciated and sorry is this is confusing!

Comment: What is your question ???

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I would like to know how to rewrite ∞−∞|()|^ 2 (sorry don't know how to format) as an integration by parts.

Comment: Welcome to [Math.SE]!  Your question is rather confusing, since it's not clear what you're actually trying to do.  Note, however, that there is in general no relation between the integral of $f(x)$ and the integral of $|f(x)|^2$.  If you have a function $f(x)$ in terms of some parameters, you just have to calculate the integral.

Comment: @AbsolutelyConfused Your question is ... confusing. Please rewrite it asking a precise question with the adequate hypothesis on $f$. Differentiability and so on.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net did my rewrite of the question help clear things up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is rather confusing as it stands.  Technically, one could apply integration by parts to this equation by assuming there exists a function $g(x)$ such that $g'(x) = f(x)$.  One could then rewrite this, via integration by parts, as
$$
\int f^*(x) f(x) \, dx = \int f^*(x) g'(x) \, dx = f^*(x) g(x) - \int g(x) {f^*}'(x) \, dx.
$$
(I'm assuming complex-valued functions here.  If they're real-valued, just drop the asterisks.)  Similarly, you could show that
$$
\int f^*(x) f(x) \, dx = x |f(x)|^2 - \int x \left( f^* f' + {f^*}' f \right) \, dx.
$$
But without further knowledge about the form of $f(x)$, it is unlikely that these facts will help you.  If you've been given the hint to use integration by parts to perform this integral for a specific $f(x)$, it seems more likely to me that there is a different decomposition that allows this to be done.